# how to synchronize 2 tabs JTabbedPane Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I work with swing to build GUI. Hello everyone

I have 2 tabs (JTabbedPane) that I want to synchronize.

For example, on the image below, I would like that if I click on the **Rent button**, the line can be automatically added to the **My leasing** tab so that if I go to the **My Leasing** tab, I find the line that has just been added.

[image]

Currently, to see the line that has just been added to the **My leasing** tab, I must log out and log back in.

Comment: Models, models, models ... Basically what you want to do, is when you click "Rent", it should update the "leasing" model.  This would generate events/notifications to which the leasing UI would respond to. This is the bases of the [model-view-controller](https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-model-view-controller/) paradigm - it also decouples your code

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I would like to do it with Swing and not the web.

Comment: I tell myself that there may be a listener to put in place but I do not know which one.

Comment: What do you think [Swing is based on](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/architecture-142923.html)? It has "models", it has "views", it even has "controllers", but you tend to not to see them directly.  MVC is a fundamental paradigm used by almost all languages and APIs.  It's a paradigm worth taking the time to understand, as it will decouple the code and the responsibilities of your classes. Your basic problem is you want to move "data" from one "view", which is a representation of a "model", to another "model", which is represented by another "view"

Comment: What you want to do, is provide some kind of lease "model" to the "vehicle" tab, which is shared with the "leasing" tab.  The leasing tab would (presumably) wrap a type of a `TableModel` around this, so it can be displayed in a `JTable`. When the "leasing model" is changed, it could generate it's own "leasing event", to which the the "leasing table model" would subscribe to and delegate the notifications up through the table API

Answer (score 0):

> I tell myself that there may be a listener to put in place but I do not know which one.

You need to respond to the click of the "Rent" button.

Check out the [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/). This class allows you to add an ActionListener which is invoked whenever the button is clicked (or activated by using the space bar).

The example code shows how to delete a row from the model. In your case you would want to copy the data from one model to the other.